# PySpark withColumn that uses column data from another row

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe like this:

| order_type | customer_id | order_id | related_order_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| purchase | 123 | abc | null |
| return | 123 | bcd | null |
| purchase | 234 | xyz | null |
| return | 234 | zzz | null |

Where I want to fill in the **related_order_id** column as the **order_id** of the related purchase, only for rows where **order_type** is **return**. A return and a purchase row can be related by their **customer_id**.

I've tried to use withColumn(), but I haven't figured out a way that would allow me to also look at other rows and their column data.
The end result should look something like

| order_type | customer_id | order_id | related_order_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| purchase | 123 | abc | null |
| return | 123 | bcd | **abc** |
| purchase | 234 | xyz | null |
| return | 234 | zzz | **xyz** |

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [lag()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lag.html) function to use data from the previous row.

Assuming a `return` is always preceded by a `purchase`, you can do:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

w = Window().partitionBy("customer_id").orderBy("order_type")

df.withColumn("related_order_id", F.when(col("order_type")=="return", \
              F.lag(col("order_id")).over(w)) \
             .otherwise(col("related_order_id"))).show()
```

Output:

```
+----------+-----------+--------+----------------+
|order_type|customer_id|order_id|related_order_id|
+----------+-----------+--------+----------------+
|  purchase|        123|     abc|            null|
|    return|        123|     bcd|             abc|
|  purchase|        234|     xyz|            null|
|    return|        234|     zzz|             xyz|
+----------+-----------+--------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to do this very efficiently with clever use of joins.

Let's make a "left" and a "right" df so we can join them:

```
df_l = df[['order_type', 'customer_id', 'order_id']]
df_l = df_l[ df_l.order_type == "return"] # so left df is returns

df_r = df[['order_type', 'customer_id', 'order_id']]\
    .withColumnRenamed('order_id', 'related_order_id')
df_r = df_r[ df_r.order_type == "purchase"] # so right df is purchases
```

Now take a left join on `customer_id`

```
df_j = df_l.join( df_r, df_l.customer_id == df_r.customer_id, 'left')
```

this joined `df_j` will have columns `['order_type', 'customer_id', 'order_id', 'related_order_id']`, and the last column should be as you desire. This `df_j` will only include the rows from the `return` items. So we can add back the others rows with `.union`. We need to add the `related_order_id` column with null values to the `purchased` dataframe first:

```
df_final = df_j.union( df_r.withColumn('related_order_id', lit( None )))
```

My guess is that this will be quite efficient.